# Update a Value in One Column Based on Criteria in Other Columns

Tags: r

If my data frame (df) looks like this:

```
Name        State
John Smith  MI
John Smith  WI
Jeff Smith  WI
```

I want to rename the John Smith from WI "John Smith1".  What is the cleanest R equivalent of the SQL statement?

```
update df 
set Name = "John Smith1"
where Name = "John Smith"
and State = "WI"
```

Comment: Maybe like this? `df[df$Name == "John_Smith" & df$State == "WI",1] <- "John_Smith1"`

Comment: RStudent is right on, in case your first column isn't of class `factor`

Comment: That almost works, but I have a very big data frame so I was trying to simplify the question.  Your solution adds "John_Smith1" to the first column of my data frame, not the df$Name column.

Comment: @FrankB. You can change the `1` to `Name` as I did in the answer

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(Name=c('John Smith', 'John Smith', 'Jeff Smith'),
                 State=c('MI','WI','WI'), stringsAsFactors=F)

df <- within(df, Name[Name == 'John Smith' & State == 'WI'] <- 'John Smith1')

> df
         Name State
1  John Smith    MI
2 John Smith1    WI
3  Jeff Smith    WI
```

** Edit **

Edited to add that you can put whatever you like in the within expression:

```
df <- within(df, {
    f <- Name == 'John Smith' & State == 'WI'
    Name[f] <- 'John Smith1'
    State[f] <- 'CA'
})
```

Comment: I wish I knew how to do that economically for updating multiple columns. This syntax appears to require duplicating the subsetting condition for each column being updated.

Comment: `within` takes an expression as the second argument. You can shove whatever you want in there. See my updated answer for an example.

Answer (score 23):

One way:

```
df[df$Name == "John_Smith" & df$State == "WI", "Name"] <- "John_Smith1"
```

Another way using the `dplyr`:

```
df %>% mutate(Name = ifelse(State == "WI" & Name == "John_Smith", "John_Smith1", Name))
```

Note: As David Arenburg says, the first column should not be a factor. For this, reading the data set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use package `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[State=="WI", Name:=paste0(Name,"1")]
```

Comment: This code will also rename `Jeff Smith` to `Jeff Smith1`. Use `setDT(df)[State == "WI" & Name == "John Smith", Name := paste0(Name, "1")]` to rename only   `John Smith` from `WI`.

Answer (score 1):

As the OP has [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28650957/update-a-value-in-one-column-based-on-criteria-in-other-columns#comment45599836_28650957) that he has "*a very big data frame*", it might be advantageous to use a binary search

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[.("John Smith",  "WI"), on = .(Name=V1, State=V2), 
          Name := paste0(Name, 1)][]
```

> ```
>           Name State
> 1:  John Smith    MI
> 2: John Smith1    WI
> 3:  Jeff Smith    WI
> ```

instead of a vector scan

```
setDT(df)[State == "WI" & Name == "John Smith", Name := paste0(Name, "1")]
```

In both variations the data object is updated by reference, i.e., without copying the whole object which save time and memory.