# R - Change values in one column if conditions in other columns are met

Tags: r

I have a matrix such as the below:

```
Area_Code <- as.character(c("Red","Yellow","Orange","Orange","Orange"))
Garden_Size <- as.numeric(c(75,100,50,170,105))
Property_Type <- as.character(c("House","Flat","Bungalow","House","House"))
House_Price <- as.numeric(c(110000,120000,355000,495000,150000))
Matrix <- cbind(Area_Code,Garden_Size,Property_Type,House_Price)
```

I would like to be able to set variables such as;
Area_Code must be Orange
Garden size must be > 100
Property type must be "House"

I would then like to increase the House_Price variable by some amount - for this example lets say 10% - if these particular conditions are met for each row.

I would like the resulting change to be saved as a new matrix so that I have a copy of the old matrix and the new updated matrix.

So for this particular example I would like the code to produce the outcome that the new matrix is identical to the old, except the bottom two rows (that match the parameters set above) have had their price increased by 10%.

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update a Value in One Column Based on Criteria in Other Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28650957/update-a-value-in-one-column-based-on-criteria-in-other-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable are various classes, so a data frame makes more sense than a matrix.

```
Area_Code <- c("Red","Yellow","Orange","Orange","Orange")
Garden_Size <- c(75,100,50,170,105)
Property_Type <- c("House","Flat","Bungalow","House","House")
House_Price <- c(110000,120000,355000,495000,150000)
df <- data.frame(Area_Code, Garden_Size, Property_Type, House_Price)
```

Here, using `dplyr` I check the conditions and increment the house price by 10% if they are met. Otherwise, there is no change.

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(House_Price = ifelse(Property_Type == "House" &
                              Area_Code == "Orange" &
                              Garden_Size > 100, 
                              House_Price * 1.1, 
                              House_Price))
```

Finally, a comparison between `df` and `df2`.

```
df

#   Area_Code Garden_Size Property_Type House_Price
# 1       Red          75         House      110000
# 2    Yellow         100          Flat      120000
# 3    Orange          50      Bungalow      355000
# 4    Orange         170         House      495000
# 5    Orange         105         House      150000

df2

#   Area_Code Garden_Size Property_Type House_Price
# 1       Red          75         House      110000
# 2    Yellow         100          Flat      120000
# 3    Orange          50      Bungalow      355000
# 4    Orange         170         House      544500
# 5    Orange         105         House      165000
```

Comment: The perfect response. Thank you so much!