# How to update name based on other column's condition (Cleaning Data)

Tags: r, string, str-replace, data-cleaning

I have a df below

```
df <- data.frame(LASTNAME = c("Robinson", "Anderson", "Beckham", "Wickham", "Carlos", "Robinson", "Beckham", "Anderson", "Carlos"),
                 FIRSTNAME = c("David", "Adi", "Joan", "Kesley", "Anberto", "Dave", "Joana", "Adien", "An"))

df <- data.frame(lapply(df, as.character), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

There are some first names are not consistent. I want to find and replace these ones. But when I put it in the function, it doesn't work. One more thing is my data is big. There are hundred of names, so are there any better ways to do it.
My code works well when it is alone (not in function), but I failed to find a way to do it if I have 100 names need to find and replace. I found a reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28650957/update-a-value-in-one-column-based-on-criteria-in-other-columns), but does not resolve my problem. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
fil_name <- function(last,first,alternative){
  df %>% 
    mutate(FIRSTNAME = ifelse(LASTNAME == "last" & FIRSTNAME == "first", "alternative", FIRSTNAME))
}
fil_name(Robinson,Dave,David)
```

## Expected output:

```
 LASTNAME   FIRSTNAME
1 Robinson     David
2 Anderson     Adien
3  Beckham     Joana
4  Wickham    Kesley
5   Carlos   Anberto
6 Robinson     David
7  Beckham     Joana
8 Anderson     Adien
9   Carlos   Anberto
```

Answer (score 1):

We can convert to character inside the function, and it should work

```
fil_name <- function(df, last,first,alternative){

         last <- rlang::as_string(rlang::ensym(last))
         first <- rlang::as_string(rlang::ensym(first))
         alternative <- rlang::as_string(rlang::ensym(alternative))
      df %>% 
       dplyr::mutate(FIRSTNAME = case_when(LASTNAME ==  last & 
                FIRSTNAME == first ~ alternative, TRUE ~ FIRSTNAME))
    }
fil_name(df, Robinson,Dave,David)
```

Comment: Your approach is super awesome. I struggled against it  to find out answer. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to create a separate data frame including the `FIRSTNAME` alternative name pairings, merge it into the original data, and update `FIRSTNAME` for those rows where `ALTNAME` is not `NA`.

This allows one to update the data with a vectorized process, rather than changing the names one by one.

```
# create data frame with a column to maintain original sort order
df <- data.frame(obs = 1:9,
                 LASTNAME = c("Robinson", "Anderson", "Beckham", "Wickham", "Carlos", "Robinson", "Beckham", "Anderson", "Carlos"),
                 FIRSTNAME = c("David", "Adi", "Joan", "Kesley", "Anberto", "Dave", "Joana", "Adien", "An"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# create firstname / altname pairs 
altnames <- data.frame(FIRSTNAME = c("Dave","Adi","Joan","An"),
                       ALTNAME = c("David","Adien","Joana","Anberto"),
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# merge by firstname, keeping all rows from original data frame
combined <- merge(df,altnames,by="FIRSTNAME",all.x=TRUE)
# update rows where ALTNAME is not NA
combined[!is.na(combined$ALTNAME),"FIRSTNAME"] <- combined[!is.na(combined$ALTNAME),"ALTNAME"]
# print the result, ordered by sequence in original data frame
combined[order(combined$obs),c("LASTNAME","FIRSTNAME")]
```

...and the output:

```
> combined[order(combined$obs),c("LASTNAME","FIRSTNAME")]
  LASTNAME FIRSTNAME
6 Robinson     David
1 Anderson     Adien
7  Beckham     Joana
9  Wickham    Kesley
4   Carlos   Anberto
5 Robinson     David
8  Beckham     Joana
2 Anderson     Adien
3   Carlos   Anberto
>
```

Comment: Your answer is definitely awesome. Thanks a lot your the solution.

Comment: @MichaelJohnson - thanks for the feedback. While the tidyverse has many useful features, sometimes its grammar leads people to implement overly complicated or non-vectorized solutions. If you have 100 names to clean, the `fil_name()` function will make 200 passes of the data frame to be cleaned. The alternate approach that merges a lookup table with the original data is much more efficient.

Comment: You're right. This approach is pretty simple and more efficient. Sometimes basic concepts are the key to solve the problem. Thank for your great feedback and solution.