# Change single cells in column based on string pattern in other column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to change column cells from 0 to 1 based on string pattern in another column. I almost found my solution here [Update a Value in One Column Based on Criteria in Other Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28650957/update-a-value-in-one-column-based-on-criteria-in-other-columns) but it doesn't quite work as it matches them perfectly using "==".

What I want

```
df_right <- data.frame( Time = c("2000W01","2000W02", "2000W03", "2000W04",
                           "2000W05","2000W06", "2000W07", "2000W08",
                           "2001W01","2001W02", "2001W03", "2001W04"
                           ,"2001W05","2001W06", "2001W07", "2001W08",
                           "2002W01","2002W02", "2002W03", "2002W04"
                           ,"2002W05","2002W06", "2002W07", "2002W08"),
                  spring = c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                  summer = c(0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0),
                  autumn = c(0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0),
                  winter = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1))

df_right
    Time spring summer autumn winter
1  2000W01      1      0      0      0
2  2000W02      1      0      0      0
3  2000W03      0      1      0      0
4  2000W04      0      1      0      0
5  2000W05      0      0      1      0
6  2000W06      0      0      1      0
7  2000W07      0      0      0      1
8  2000W08      0      0      0      1
9  2001W01      1      0      0      0
10 2001W02      1      0      0      0
11 2001W03      0      1      0      0
12 2001W04      0      1      0      0
13 2001W05      0      0      1      0
14 2001W06      0      0      1      0
15 2001W07      0      0      0      1
16 2001W08      0      0      0      1
17 2002W01      1      0      0      0
18 2002W02      1      0      0      0
19 2002W03      0      1      0      0
20 2002W04      0      1      0      0
21 2002W05      0      0      1      0
22 2002W06      0      0      1      0
23 2002W07      0      0      0      1
24 2002W08      0      0      0      1
```

I used this code

```
mutate(season = case_when(grepl('W01|W02', Time) ~ 'spring', 
                             grepl('W03|W04', Time) ~ 'summer', 
                             grepl('W05|W06', Time) ~ 'autumn', 
                             grepl('W07|W08', Time) ~ 'winter')) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = season, values_from = season, 
               values_fn = length, values_fill = 0)
```

But for some reason some of the cells are empty like this where spring and autumn failed for all spring and autumn-weeks. I fiddled around with `mutate` a bit but would appreciate a simple solution like"if df$Time have W02" then spring in that row = 1"

```
     Time spring summer autumn winter
1  2000W01      1      0      0      0
2  2000W02      0      0      0      0
3  2000W03      0      1      0      0
4  2000W04      0      1      0      0
5  2000W05      0      0      0      0
6  2000W06      0      0      1      0
7  2000W07      0      0      0      1
8  2000W08      0      0      0      1
9  2001W01      1      0      0      0
10 2001W02      0      0      0      0
11 2001W03      0      1      0      0
12 2001W04      0      1      0      0
13 2001W05      0      0      0      0
14 2001W06      0      0      1      0
15 2001W07      0      0      0      1
16 2001W08      0      0      0      1
17 2002W01      1      0      0      0
18 2002W02      0      0      0      0
19 2002W03      0      1      0      0
20 2002W04      0      1      0      0
21 2002W05      0      0      0      0
22 2002W06      0      0      1      0
23 2002W07      0      0      0      1
24 2002W08      0      0      0      1
```

dput

```
structure(list(geo = c("AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", 
"AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", 
"AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", 
"AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", 
"AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", 
"AL", "AL"), Time = c("2000W01", "2000W02", "2000W03", "2000W04", 
"2000W05", "2000W06", "2000W07", "2000W08", "2000W09", "2000W10", 
"2000W11", "2000W12", "2000W13", "2000W14", "2000W15", "2000W16", 
"2000W17", "2000W18", "2000W19", "2000W20", "2000W21", "2000W22", 
"2000W23", "2000W24", "2000W25", "2000W26", "2000W27", "2000W28", 
"2000W29", "2000W30", "2000W31", "2000W32", "2000W33", "2000W34", 
"2000W35", "2000W36", "2000W37", "2000W38", "2000W39", "2000W40", 
"2000W41", "2000W42", "2000W43", "2000W44", "2000W45", "2000W46", 
"2000W47", "2000W48", "2000W49", "2000W50", "2000W51", "2000W52", 
"2001W01"), winter = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), spring = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), summer = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), autumn = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -53L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: You should include your `df`  from which you want to obtain this `df_right`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your sentence "if df$Time have W02" then spring in that row = 1" describes what you want to do, then that should work:

```
df$spring <- ifelse(grepl("W02$", df$Time), df$spring == 1, df$spring)
```

Alternatively:

```
df$spring[grepl("W02$",df$Time)] <- 1
```

In `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(spring = ifelse(grepl("W02$", Time), 1, spring))
```

Comment: It makes so much sense but I can't see the change in my dataframe. I get no error or anything. What could be wrong?

Comment: To help you need to post the dataframe that you want to change. Can you do that?

Comment: I'm trying head(df,40) but don't know how to get the code behind it so you can copy it

Comment: Use `dput(df[1:40,])`

Comment: Thanks for the data. `df %>% mutate(spring = ifelse(grepl("W02$", Time), 1, spring)) ` works. Have you tried it?

Comment: Okay that works! And I am confused. Is this because I am in the tidyverse that I can't use base-R commands?

Comment: The tidyverse works with `base R` commands as well, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

You may do something like this in `tidyverse` to get your `df_right`

```
df %>% mutate(season = case_when(substr(Time, 6, 7) %in% c('01', '02') ~ 'spring',
                                 substr(Time, 6, 7) %in% c('03', '04') ~ 'summer',
                                 substr(Time, 6, 7) %in% c('05', '06') ~ 'autumn',
                                 TRUE ~ 'winter')) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Time, names_from = season, values_fill = 0, values_fn = length, values_from = season)

# A tibble: 24 x 5
   Time    spring summer autumn winter
   <chr>    <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
 1 2000W01      1      0      0      0
 2 2000W02      1      0      0      0
 3 2000W03      0      1      0      0
 4 2000W04      0      1      0      0
 5 2000W05      0      0      1      0
 6 2000W06      0      0      1      0
 7 2000W07      0      0      0      1
 8 2000W08      0      0      0      1
 9 2001W01      1      0      0      0
10 2001W02      1      0      0      0
# ... with 14 more rows
```

where `df` is

```
df <- data.frame( Time = c("2000W01","2000W02", "2000W03", "2000W04",
                           "2000W05","2000W06", "2000W07", "2000W08",
                           "2001W01","2001W02", "2001W03", "2001W04"
                           ,"2001W05","2001W06", "2001W07", "2001W08",
                           "2002W01","2002W02", "2002W03", "2002W04"
                           ,"2002W05","2002W06", "2002W07", "2002W08"))
```